# How to encode string in sinatra using AES?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Spent a lot of my time searching a way of ecrypting string in my app, but didn't find a right solution to use it in Sinatra. For example, I tried to 'require aes' gem (https://github.com/chicks/aes) also gibberish (https://github.com/defunkt/gibberish/blob/master/lib/gibberish.rb) gem but all time I see errors in browser.

I try to encrypt message field in my app:

```
require 'aes'

get '/auth/signup' do
  user = User.new(url: Helpers.random, message: AES.encrypt("A super secret message", 'Here we go!'))
  user.save
end
```

Please, help me how to solve this?!

Comment: Can you define "errors in the browser" better?

Comment: LoadError: cannot load such file -- aes

Comment: You may need to use `gem 'aes'` first.

Comment: Placed **gem 'aes'** on first line - 2 errors disappeared, 12 errors still exist

Comment: Problem #1 solved. You'll need to describe the other problems in another question if you can, preferably with a lot more specificity, like the exact errors you're getting.

Comment: No, **cannot load such file -- aes** still exists

Comment: The code I've put in my answer with `Gemfile` works on my machine with Ruby 2.6.3 and should work on yours.

Comment: "all time I see errors in browser" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: @JörgWMittag nice catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Ruby gems you need to declare them up-front. The easiest way is:

```
gem 'aes'
require 'aes'
```

You can also use [Bundler](https://bundler.io) and declare them in a `Gemfile` like:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org/'

gem 'aes'
```

Then in your code:

```
require 'bundler/setup'

require 'aes'
```

Where `Gemfile` describes all your dependencies so you can easily reinstall them if necessary.

Once you've created the `Gemfile` you can do `bundle install`. If that has issues you'll be alerted. `bundle check` can verify everything's set up properly.

Comment: Thank you very much, I changed it, didn't help, then restarted server - voila))

Comment: @JessieScinor use rerun to automatically restart your Sinatra server when you change some sourcecode https://rubygems.org/gems/rerun/versions/0.11.0

Comment: @peter I used shotgun for auto reloading

Comment: Most auto-reloaders only watch for changes in particular files, and things like `Gemfile` require hard stopping and starting since it changes the fundamentals.

Comment: rerun is configurable for the extensions it needs to watch, used to use sinatra/reloader but it has issues when using active record and daemons